# How can I return redirect back to a modal in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a modal and that will trigger when my user click on **Log in.**

[image]

---

## Logic

If the authentication fail, I want to re-direct back to this modal.

With that in mind, I want to re-direct :

- back to my homepage
- trigger this modal
- flash my session in there.

---

## HTML

**Btn**

`<a class="btn btn-default" id="btn-login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>`

**Modal**

```
<!--Login Modal-->
<div class="light-skin modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="form" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login here</h4>

        {{-- Session     --}}
         @include('layouts.session')


      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="login-form" role="form" method="post" action="/">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

          {!! Form::token() !!}
          </form>

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

## AccountController : postSignIn function, at the end ...

```
if($auth) {
    return Redirect::to('/dist')
    ->with('success','You have been successfully logged in.')
    ;
}
else {

    $url = URL::to('/').'#loginModal';

    return Redirect::to($url)
    ->with('error','Username/Password Wrong or account has not been activated !')
    ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
    ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Nothing is trigger. Any hints anyone ?

Comment: Is the modal triggered via Javascript? If so, you'll need to do it via Javascript when the page loads.

Comment: 2 options that I can see: 1. Reload the page with some kind of flag/session variable that specifies that a modal should be opened or 2. Do your backend stuff via `ajax` and never actually close the modal/redirect the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Tim Lewis** and **@Kryten** for point me to the right direction.

I'm sure there is more than 1 way to do this, but here how I get mine to work.

```
<?php $error = Session::get('error');  ?>

// If there is error, the modal will be trigger.
@if(!empty($error) )
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#loginModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endif
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/6xyudLs8/